# FormatException with String.Format and DateTime from DataReader

Tags: c#

I've written  code which uses a stored procedure, that works. But i get a `System.FormatException` here:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{               
    PrichinatextBox.Text = (string)rdr["Prichina"];  
    dateEdit.Text = (string.Format("{yyyy-MM-dd}", rdr["data"]));  //error format exception                
}
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные добавлены");
```

Write code for realize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess, you get a `System.FormatException` here

```
dateEdit.Text = (string.Format("{yyyy-MM-dd}", rdr["data"]));
```

That is because you can't use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) in that way, a format string must have an index or the index must be preceeded like here:

```
dateEdit.Text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", rdr["data"]);
```

or without `String.Format` but `DateTime.ToString`:

```
int columndIndex = rdr.GetOrdinal("data");
DateTime dt = rdr.GetDateTime(columndIndex);
dateEdit.Text = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```